# ContainerView's Child Instance Reference

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

See the image below; how can I get the value of the UITextField "txtFullName" when the user clicks on UIButton "btnSaveSettings".  I want to show an UIAlertView with the txtFullName.Text value inside that alert.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The diagram doesn't look like Settings is a child. It looks like separate controller.

If your table view is a child of First View then define 2 properties (members).
In First View define member MyTableView. In TablevView you have txtFullName so access will be in FirstView as myTableView.txtFullName.

If your Table View is not a child then use ViewModel or any other method to pass data between controllers

Comment: Thanks. The table view is a child of a tableviewcontroller.  The tableviewcontroller is being referenced inside the left view controller but inside a view container.  How do I pass a model into that or even the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I sort of figured it out, thought I don't know if its the best approach.

1. I made the TableViewControllers modifier public
2. I created an instance of the txtFullName inside the TableViewController calling it Field_txtFullName, and marking it as public
3. I created an instance of the TableViewController in my AppDelegate making that public also
4. I set the AppDelegates TableViewController instance to "this" inside the TableViewController ViewDidLoad class/method
5. Then referenced the AppDelgates TableViewController instance Field_txtFullName in the parent's class, and it worked!!

I understand this may not be the cleanest way to do it, but it works.  Here is my solution incase anyone wants to take a look, but please comment if you do!
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41261911/ThirdAttemptTableViewController.zip